# Google Webmasters Tools strange 404 errors referred from same site

Tags: google-search-console, 404, crawl-errors

Starting about a month ago, I noticed a sudden increase in 404 errors in Webmasters Tools for one of my sites (over 1400 errors so far). All the errors are being referred from my own site to non existent pages. The 404 error URLs are all of the same format:

URL:
http://www.helloneighbour.com/save/1347208508000

The number on the end appears to be a timestamp followed by 3 zeros. The referring page, in this case is :

Linked from
http://www.helloneighbour.com/save/cmw-insurance-insurance-burnaby

When I look at the source code of that page, or I use Webmaster tools to view the page as Google sees it,  I can't find any link that comes close to what is above. I built the site, and I can't find any place that might be causing these false links either. The server logs (access and error) don't show Google or anyone else trying to access these links.

I've marked all these pages as fixed, and waited a couple of weeks, only to find the errors come back again over the last few days.

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen anything strange like this, or if someone might have a way for me to debug, replicate this error myself.

Comment: Google just notified me that another site, on a different server, using completely different software now has almost 1000 404 errors. I was totally surprised to discover they are almost the identical format as above: jonpeddie.com/reviews/comments/1346819584000. Is it possible that Google is having issues, as unlikely as that may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. Once I posted a followup comment above I managed to craft a better Google search term and found that Disqus is causing the issue. There is no solution that I can see of yet. There is an explanation of the problem here: 
http://www.seroundtable.com/disqus-google-errors-15663.html